# The parameter in the function given to an array of buttons with onClick.AddListener, is the same for every button

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i really tried my best to explain this, but it's very complicated.

i'm trying to make a Delete Level System. I instantiate a bunch of buttons that are connected to a bunch of folders(The levels) in the Application.persistentDataPath.

When instantiating these buttons i give them a listener(onClick.AddListener(delegate { DeleteLevel(folderName); });) and a parameter(the level name, same name as the folder) when i want to delete i use the button folderName, but it is always the same as the first button i use.

The Error:
"DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\Matteo\AppData\LocalLow\hacertime\Imp\levels\Level'.
System.IO.FileSystem.GetFindData (System.String fullPath, Interop+Kernel32+WIN32_FIND_DATA& findData) (at :0)
System.IO.FileSystem.RemoveDirectory (System.String fullPath, System.Boolean recursive) (at :0)
System.IO.Directory.Delete (System.String path, System.Boolean recursive) (at :0)
LoadScript+<>c__DisplayClass10_0.b__0 () (at Assets/Scripts/LoadScript.cs:55)
UnityEngine.Events.InvokableCall.Invoke () (at :0)
UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent.Invoke () (at :0)
UnityEngine.UI.Button.Press () (at ./Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ugui@1.0.0/Runtime/UI/Core/Button.cs:70)
UnityEngine.UI.Button.OnPointerClick (UnityEngine.EventSystems.PointerEventData eventData) (at ./Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ugui@1.0.0/Runtime/UI/Core/Button.cs:114)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute (UnityEngine.EventSystems.IPointerClickHandler handler, UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData eventData) (at ./Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ugui@1.0.0/Runtime/EventSystem/ExecuteEvents.cs:57)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute[T] (UnityEngine.GameObject target, UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData eventData, UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents+EventFunction`1[T1] functor) (at ./Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ugui@1.0.0/Runtime/EventSystem/ExecuteEvents.cs:272)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem:Update() (at ./Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ugui@1.0.0/Runtime/EventSystem/EventSystem.cs:530)"

You probably didn't understand anything, so i'll show a video.

https://youtu.be/5F9pFsl5S_A

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Button = UnityEngine.UI.Button;

public class LoadScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform Content;
    public GameObject LevelButton;

    public TMP_InputField NameInputField;
    public static string StaticLevelName;

    public bool DeleteMode;

    public GameObject DeleteMenu;
    public Button YesButton;
    public Button NoButton;

    public void NewLevel()
    {
        StaticLevelName = NameInputField.text;

        string folderPath = Application.persistentDataPath + "/levels";

        if (!Directory.Exists(folderPath))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath);
        }

        Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath + "/" + StaticLevelName);
        File.WriteAllText(folderPath + "/" + StaticLevelName + "/level.json", JsonConvert.Null);

        SceneManager.LoadScene("Editor");
    }

    public void LoadEditorWithLevelName(string LevelName)
    {
        if (DeleteMode == true) return;

        StaticLevelName = LevelName;

        SceneManager.LoadScene("Editor");
    }

    public void DeleteLevel(string LevelName)
    {
        if(DeleteMode == false) return;

        DeleteMenu.SetActive(true);

        YesButton.onClick.AddListener(delegate { Directory.Delete(Application.persistentDataPath + "/levels/" + LevelName, true); 
            DeleteMenu.SetActive(false); Reload(); });
        NoButton.onClick.AddListener(delegate { DeleteMenu.SetActive(false); });
    }

    public void DeleteModeON()
    {
        DeleteMode = true;
    }
    public void DeleteModeOFF()
    {
        DeleteMode = false;
    }

    public void Reload()
    {
        foreach (Transform button in Content)
        {
            Destroy(button.gameObject);
        }

        string folderPath = Application.persistentDataPath + "/levels";

        if (!Directory.Exists(folderPath))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath);
        }

        string[] folderNames = Directory.GetDirectories(folderPath);

        List<string> folderNamesWithoutPath = new List<string>();

        foreach (string folderName in folderNames)
        {
            folderNamesWithoutPath.Add(Path.GetFileName(folderName));
        }

        foreach (string folderName in folderNamesWithoutPath)
        {
            GameObject NewObject = Instantiate(LevelButton, Content);

            NewObject.transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<TMP_Text>().text = folderName;

            NewObject.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(delegate { LoadEditorWithLevelName(folderName); });
            NewObject.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(delegate { DeleteLevel(folderName); });
        }
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        DeleteMode = false;

        Reload();
    }
}
```

i'm desparate, i've been trying to fix this for many hours. any help, helps.

Comment: public void DeleteLevel(string LevelName)
    {
        if(DeleteMode == false) return;

        DeleteMenu.SetActive(true);

        YesButton.onClick.AddListener(delegate { Directory.Delete(Application.persistentDataPath + "/levels/" + LevelName, true); 
            DeleteMenu.SetActive(false); /LevelName = null/; Reload(); });
        NoButton.onClick.AddListener(delegate { DeleteMenu.SetActive(false); });
    }

i added /LevelName = null;/ and when i do this after the second level deletion it deletes everything.

Comment: Yes! i fixed it. i just needed to remove all the listeners to the yesandno buttons.

Comment: You are *capturing* your iterator variable in the delegate .. despite the way the loop reads intuitively all your delegates share the very same instance of `folderName` => the last iteration overwrites it with the final value and on click for any of those buttons it will always be that very last value (see linked duplicate) .. solution is basically to introduce a scoped variable within the loop body like e.g. `var folder = folderName;` which can safely be captured by the delegates without getting overwritten by the next iteration ;)